# Yum Install Issue

Tags: g++, rpm, yum, libstdc++

I am trying to install g++ 4.1.2 (seems gcc 4.1.2 is already installed) in a Redhat Linux 6 machine. When I first tried running gcc-c++-4.1.2 rpm through yum, I get the following dependency issues,

```
[root@Cham1WS Desktop]# yum install gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm 
Setting up Install Process 
Examining gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm: gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
Marking gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm to be installed 
Resolving Dependencies 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-55.el5 for package: gcc-c++-  4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.1.2-55.el5 for package: gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
--> Finished Dependency Resolution 
Error: Package: gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64) 
       Requires: libstdc++-devel = 4.1.2-55.el5 
Error: Package: gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64) 
       Requires: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-55.el5 
       Installed: libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-   RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201507020259.x86_64/6.7) 
           libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6 
           libstdc++ = 4.4.7-16.el6 
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem 
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So, it seems I need to install libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm. So I tried installing it and I get the follwoing dependencies,

```
[root@Cham1WS Desktop]# yum install libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm 
Setting up Install Process 
Examining libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
Marking libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm to be installed 
Resolving Dependencies 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-55.el5 for package: libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
--> Finished Dependency Resolution 
Error: Package: libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 (/libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64) 
       Requires: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-55.el5 
       Installed: libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201507020259.x86_64/6.7) 
           libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6 
           libstdc++ = 4.4.7-16.el6 
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem 
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems an earlier version of libstdc++ is already installed. Anyways, I tried installing libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm (not the "devel"), and it says it's already installed.

```
[root@Cham1WS Desktop]# yum install libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm 
Setting up Install Process 
Examining libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64 
libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

But if I try to install the "libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-55.el5.x86_64.rpm" I get the ealier dependencies again. It seems the issue is that I have a newer version of libstdc++ is already installed

1) How do I fix this issue?
2) Do I need to uninstall the later version of libstdc++?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `yum` the wrong way: You should let yum connect to some repositories, and let him figure out the dependencies.

By the way you are installing *el5* packages, that means packages for centos5, not centos6. Try finding similar packages but for centos6, that would be better; try using the *epel* repository which might help you (take a look here on how to enable it: https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/)

Comment: Since I am using an offline computer, how can I let yum connect to the repositories?